# SBT dependency on non-SBT library

Tags: maven, sbt

My Play/SBT project needs to depend on a third-party Java library that is distributed in source form and can be built with either Ant or Maven. Its root directory contains `pom.xml` and `build.xml`.

I am thinking of having this library added as a git submodule and have SBT build it as a subproject. I tried adding

```
externalPom(baseDirectory(_ / "pathToLibrary" / "pom.xml"))
```

to my build settings, but I ended up with the following compiler error:

```
[info] Compiling 32 Scala sources and 5 Java sources to /home/thesamet/project]
[error] (compile:compile) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 23, 2013 11:46:20 AM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An external pom can only be used to obtain [library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#maven-pom-dependencies-only) of the maven project but not compile it.

You can add an sbt build configuration for the external project or easier, you can publish the third-party module to a corporate Maven or Ivy repository or just local with `mvn install` and add ~/.m2 as [file resolver](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html) to your SBT project.